# Elasticsearch ingest attachment processor with OCR

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I want to ingest text from images and scanned pdfs into elastic and I know that ingest atachement processor is based on Apache Tika and Apache Tika should have a Tesseract OCR support.

Is it possible somehow to enable it? And if yes, wouldn't that violate elastic licensing agreements?

Answer (score 0):

To ingest text from images, pdf, etc. you can use [fscrawler](https://fscrawler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

My recommendation: use [workplace search](https://www.elastic.co/enterprise-search/workplace-search).

> Full text content extraction The following file types are supported
> for full text extraction:
>
> .doc .docx .html .odt .one .md .markdown .paper .pdf .ppt .pptx .rtf
> .txt .xls .xlsx Formatted text files are normalized to decrease
> whitespace and minimize storage costs:
>
> .md .markdown .paper .rtf .txt

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/workplace-search/current/content-sources-content-extraction.html#content-sources-content-extraction-text

[image]

Comment: I have documents saved in MySQL database in base64 format. that I wanted to ingest into elastic. I think FScrawler is a little bit more suited to work with a file system. However it is possible to use it as REST service and send to it data from MySQL, but I don't think that is a perfect solution for my use case.

Comment: I am not really decided to use paid features of elastic, so I can't use workplace search too

Comment: workplace search is a free feature https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions

Comment: Okay, thank you, but still is it possible to enable ocr of apache Tika?